# Can I make a window react to inputs when im not on it?

Tags: python

During my weekend, I made a code that would change the color of my keyboard as I typed. (Depending on what keys I pressed). Everything works fine, as it was a relatively simple project. However, it only changes the color of my keyboard while I am on that window. I would like it to change while I'm typing anywhere, as I think it would be kind of cool. Is there any way I could do that?

Comment: Kindly consider adding samples of your code, so others might help more effectively

Answer (score 0):

The `keyboard` library might be helpful:
https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

In your code you could write something like

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('my+key+combo', changeColor, args=('myAmazingColor'))
```